# How to send request information with Sentry's new unified SDK?

Tags: node.js, sentry

The legacy Sentry Node SDK ([raven](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-node)) allowed sending HTTP request information along with the error, by passing the request object inside the `options` object (2nd argument):

```js
Raven.captureException(someError, { req: req });
```

Line of code extracted from the documentation: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/node/usage/#raven-recording-breadcrumbs

With that we could get additional context about the error, such as what was the device being used.

Is there any way we can pass the request object with the new SDK? The [context](https://docs.sentry.io/enriching-error-data/context/?platform=node) section of the [new SDK](https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/quickstart/?platform=node) explains how to send data such as user identification, custom tags, etc by using scopes, but no request option is available in there. Does this mean that the request information should now be manually sent inside `tags` and/or `extra` objects?

Comment: Generally request information should be set by integrations. Where does the request data that you want to set come from?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer it would be the `req` object coming from the Express framework, just like in the previous Sentry node.js SDK. The description of the `req` field for the legacy SDK is: "The request object associated with this event, from a Node http server, Express, Koa, or similar"

Comment: We have an express integration that I think is supposed to capture this data automatically: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/express/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MarkusUnterwaditzer shared, the Express integration worked for me: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/express/ The key parts are adding the `Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler()` middleware and then either the errorHandler middleware or doing `Sentry.captureException(error)` yourself (with no need to pass in `{req: req}`).

Sample code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://8f0620a3bfea4f2ca26aefb074851e23@sentry.io/280382' });

// The request handler must be the first middleware on the app
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());

app.get('/', function mainHandler(req, res) {
  throw new Error('Broke!');
});

// The error handler must be before any other error middleware
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

// Optional fallthrough error handler
app.use(function onError(err, req, res, next) {
  // The error id is attached to `res.sentry` to be returned
  // and optionally displayed to the user for support.
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end(res.sentry + '\n');
});

app.listen(3000);
```